# Batch File Xcopy specific file only

Tags: batch-file, batch-processing, xcopy

Would like to seek your help on creating simple bat file that will copy specific file from source to destination.
Eg.

```
Source = C:\Source
Dest = D:\Destination
```

File in source:

```
123.CSV
234.CSV
456.CSV
567.CSV
678.CSV
789.CSV
012.CSV
```

and I only want to copy the ff:

```
123.CSV
456.CSV
678.CSV
012.CSV
```

and delete others after copying.

Script:

```
@ECHO OFF

CHCP 65001 > NUL


FOR /F "usebackq delims=" %%I IN ("G:\SOURCE\123.CSV") DO (
    xcopy /s "G:\SOURCE\123%%I" "G:\DESTINATION\%%I*"
)

PAUSE
```

Thank you for your help in advance

Comment: Where are you stuck on using one of the many commands Microsoft Provides for copying files? Robocopy, Xcopy, and just Copy. To delete a file use the DEL command. Please take the [tour]. Please read [ask] a good question. Then provide a [mcve] of the code you are trying to use to solve your problem.

Comment: @Squashman noted man i updated the details above

Comment: The `FOR /F` command you are using reads the contents of a file and for each line it reads it assigns the output of the line to the `FOR` meta-variable `%%I`.  Why are you doing that?  You made no mention of using a file as the source for what files you want to copy. You also made no mention of copying these files from subdirectories and the `XCOPY` code is doing so.

Comment: @Squashmanh hello in above inquiry mentioned: I only want to copy the ff files:

123.CSV
456.CSV
678.CSV
012.CSV

Source Folder: "G:\SOURCE\123%%I"

Basically i want to copy only 10 CSV files from source folder, however that folder has 100 Plus .CSV file.

Comment: So what is stopping you from just doing a simple brute force with 10 `XCOPY` commands? `xcopy "G:\SOURCE\123.csv" "G:\DESTINATION\"`. Rinse and repeat.

Comment: Or one big long `ROBOCOPY` command. `robocopy "G:\SOURCE" "G:\DESTINATION" "123.CSV" "456.CSV" "678.CSV" "012.CSV"`

Comment: @Squashman yah that could also work.
But or yah robo copy could be better and more clean thanks mate, simple but helpful just have limited idea on scripting.

Comment: What's the exact rule about which files to copy and which not?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This works fine.
Or one big long ROBOCOPY command. robocopy "G:\SOURCE" "G:\DESTINATION" "123.CSV" "456.CSV" "678.CSV" "012.CSV" – @squashman